# Store JSON in an sqlite field?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, data-storage

I'm writing an application that communicates with a web API, which responds with JSON. Currently, I'm translating the JSON objects to Java objects using [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) (which is awesome, by the way).

Now, I want to store some of these objects in an SQLite database. However, they have lots of properties that would never be used in queries (i.e. I won't be `ORDER`ing, `WHERE`ing, or anything like that with those properties), so I feel it's unnecessary to create columns for all of them. What I'm thinking of doing is:

- Only have columns for the essential data that will be used when querying the database
- Have one `TEXT` or `BLOB` column (which one do you recommend?) that stores the actual JSON, so I can recreate my Java object from it and access all the data.

This would both make my life easier and streamline my code (I would not have to write *very* different code when dealing with data from the API vs. data from the database).

However, although I see no downsides, it feels a bit fishy.

What kind of trouble do you think I would run into if I use this technique?

Comment: It would technically be a violation of normalization rules - fields whose values depend on other fields, but normalization rules are suggestions, not carved-in-stone-you-MUST-do-it-this-way laws.

Comment: In my app, I store JSON data in a `TEXT` field, but it's data that doesn't merit its own table.

Comment: @Marc I like how you translated "fishy" in "violation of normalization rules" :) (yes, I know what they are)

Comment: @Felix, it's been quite some time since you asked this question. Did you go ahead with JSON in the database? I'm considering doing the same thing, but as you've put it, it feels fishy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing I wouldn't like about it is relying on the structure of the stored/retrieved JSON to be valid, since it's completely out of the hands of the database.  Not that you can't take precautions against possible issues, but if the JSON is somehow truncated or otherwise compromised in a way that trips up the parser, you're then missing the entire object instead of just one invalid or truncated property.  If that's an acceptable risk, then it's probably a reasonable technique.

Comment: Under what circumstances would the value get truncated? If it's out of the hands of the database then are you talking about hardware failure? If yes, then I guess I can take that risk (probably worse things would happen in case of hardware failure).

Comment: I mean due to human error rather than hardware failure - if invalid JSON makes it into the database somehow, it happens silently.  Between your JSON library and the default behavior of SQLite, that *shouldn't* happen, but if it does, the consequences are larger than if you had let the database manage the structure of the data itself.