# the best database for storing a large JSON

Tags: android, json, performance, sqlite, realm

I have a large file of json after the parsing using JACKSON, I must store it into a database, it takes a several minutes so my questions 
1-there's any way to speed up the storage ?
2- there's another database ?
3- Using Object database could help me ?,
 I use SQLITE Database, I heared about RealM but I'm not sure to use it, help me guys

Comment: Show how you are inserting json in db

Comment: check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525298/store-json-in-an-sqlite-field

Comment: Like it is suggested below, it would be better to write to file or just pull down the data you need -  not everything at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes in SQLite are ACID (atomic, consistent, isolated, durable). This means that every update, insert and delete operation is ACID. Unfortunately this requires some overhead in the database processing therefore you should wrap updates in the SQLite database in an transaction and commit this transaction after several operations. This can significantly improve performance.

The following code demonstrates that performance optimization.

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
   for (int i= 0; i< values.lenght; i++){
     // TODO prepare ContentValues object values
     db.insert(your_table, null, values);
     // In case you do larger updates
     yieldIfContededSafely()
     }
     db.setTransactionSuccessful();     
    } finally {
      db.endTransaction();
}
```

REfs:http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Transactions will reduce insertion time by around 90%

Answer (score 1):

If you're storing directly the json inside sqlite you're probably doing something "wrong".

A database is useful when you need RELATIONSHIPs beetween objects, and so you have tables, indexes, keys and stuff like that.

Anyway, it's really strange that it takes minutes, but I suggest you to rethink your architecture, and maybe just write it on a file.